# Laravel When Upload POST File, give the 403 error in Apache Web Server

Tags: laravel, apache, laravel-7

i have VPS Ubuntu Server with Apache and Laravel Controller that upload an file with 100 MB size, and it's using ajax to Send the file.
The problem is when i am testing in my Ubuntu Laptop it's working fine but when i tried in my windows clients it throw 403 code.

Some friends in the cloud suggest to change the ownership and the htaccess setting, and i changed it to www-data user, but it's not resolved the problem.

Here my .htaccess in my (root) Laravel:

```
 LimitRequestBody 2147483647
php_value post_max_size 500M
php_value upload_max_filesize 500M
Options +FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

And Here my .htaccess in public folder:

```
LimitRequestBody 2147483647

php_value post_max_size 500M
php_value upload_max_filesize 500M

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Is there any problem from my .htaccess?

Comment: Make sure you have 775 permission in your storage folder.
`chmod -R 775 storage/` 
`chmod -R 775 bootstrap/cache`

Comment: I already set the storage folder permissions set to 777, but nothing work